# Computer keeps restarting in games

Tags: windows-7, reboot, gaming

I just bought a new PSU and video card so this problem might be related to that, but every time I fire up my favorite games (WoW and TF2), my computer will reboot without warning after playing for some time.

**Here are my specs:**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Core i7 950 stock
- ASUS P6TD Deluxe
- 6 GB Corsair Dominator @ 1600mhz
- Radeon 5870 (slightly overclocked)
- Corsair 850W modular PSU (brand new)

As I mentioned, it started happening more frequently after upgrading to the new power supply. What would happen once a week before is now happening 3-4 times a day. I upgraded from a 650W Corsair.

**EDIT:** Clocking my video card a little bit lower fixed this.

Comment: Have you checked the temperatures of your CPU and GPU during game play?

Answer (score 4):

Issues like this are often caused or related to overheating components. Try making a log whilst the game runs with a program like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) (you can find logging in `Configure` > `Log`) of your CPU and GPU temperatures, especially. If these figures seem high, they may well be the cause of your problem. If the CPU is overheating at stock frequency/voltage, it may mean that the heatsink is not properly secured, or the TIM has not properly interfaced the CPU heatspreader and the heatsink. In this case, resecure the heatsink and refresh the TIM. If the GPU seems to be overheating, try downclocking (yes, frequency has an effect on temperature), and if you want to you can also try undervolting, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you know what you're doing.

However, I think the most likely thing is that you have an unstable GPU overclock. What have you done to test the stability of the clocks you are running with?

Comment: It shouldn't be overheating since I monitor my temps religiously and nothing ever gets too crazy. My PC idles at 35-40C and maxes at around 45-50C when gaming.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's from OCing the video card too aggressively. I just turned it off and will test. It was oc'd to what Auto-Tune set it at.